# IMAP Folder structures

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have to implement an client application that need to sync IMAP messages. But currently IMAP server that store messages are not ready yet and i need to finish my task. So i am using to Gmail for testing my implementation of retrieving IMAP messages.

I simulate what the spec said for the folder structures in Gmail. Creating folder and subfolders.

```
/Default

/Default/User1/Session1

/Default/User1/Session1/File1

/Default/User1/Session2

/Default/User2/Session1

/Default/User3
```

Then i use java mail to list out the folders under default.

```
store.getFolder("Default").list("*");
```

I loop the folder to print out the folder count and folder name. The returned folder includes all the subfolders of each User like above.

I would like to know is this the way that IMAP server return for the folder list query? all the subfolders under it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use list(*"), yes.  If you only want one level use list("%").  This is well explained in the [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#list(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I check the javadocs, it mentioned that "This method can be invoked on a closed Folder". So i think that i can invoke also when the folder open. But when i list("%") through the open folder to get subfolders, it always return empty. So after i changed ton get before open, then subfolders can query successfully.

Comment: Sounds like your IMAP server is broken.  Are you still using Gmail?  Can you post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing what happens when you try to list with a closed folder and then what happens when you list with the same folder but opened?

Comment: Hi Bill, due to the replied is too long, i posted as answer :)